# How to check the base of a number entered using this program?

Tags: c

My program converts the entered number to a desired base. But I want to check the present base of the number. For example : Base 1 is 3 and entered number is 4 so it isn't possible. I wrote the function to check that. But it doesn't work. Where is my fault ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int tmp_number , int source_base)
{
    int check = 0 ;
    char msg[tmp_number];
    sprintf(msg, "%d", tmp_number);
    int i=0;
    if(source_base>tmp_number)
    {
    return 1;
    }
 while( tmp_number )
    {

        if(check<source_base)
        {
        check =  tmp_number % 10 ;
        tmp_number /= 10 ;
        i++;
        }

    }
     if (sizeof(msg)==i)
     {
     return 1;
     }
    else
     {
     return 0;
     }

}

int main()
{

    int tmp_number=1;
    int decimal=0;
    int source_base,target_base;
    char s[9];
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the base1\n");
    scanf("%d",&source_base);

    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&tmp_number);
    } while (!check(tmp_number,source_base));

    printf("Enter the base2\n");
    scanf("%d",&target_base);


     while( tmp_number )
    {
    decimal += (tmp_number % 10) * pow( source_base, i ) ;
    tmp_number /= 10 ;
    ++i ;
    }
    itoa(decimal, s, target_base);
    printf("The result is %s\n", s);

   getchar();
    getchar();

return 1; 
}
```

Comment: "But it doesn't work" - not helpful. What does it do?

Comment: I tried to understand what you `really` intend to ask and then I gave up.You are definitely struggling with English,but that's ok, try once again.Further,it helps to include some `printf()`s in the program to get an idea what's going on in it.

Comment: You cound use the unix/linux program "bc"; it does this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
char msg[tmp_number];
```

Creates a really big array (the size of the value of your number, not the length of your number), and `sizeof(msg) == i` will only be true when the number is exactly `1`. You could fix your code by finding the length of the number and creating an array of that size, but it would be better to rewrite it a bit like this:

```
int check(int tmp_number , int source_base)
{

    int check;
    while( tmp_number )
    {
        check = tmp_number % 10;
        tmp_number /= 10 ;

        if(check >= source_base)
            return 0;

    }

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Could you give more information ? . I made this but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you understand what I said about `char msg[tmp_number];` creating a massive array? If `tmp_number` is 324132 it creates an array of size 324132, not an array of size 6.

Comment: Okay I got it. But I can still enter 4 for base 3.

Comment: @user1873885 Are you sure? When I call `check(4,3);` I get `0`.

Comment: I couldn't understand. I get always 1

Comment: Okey I handle it :) Thank you paulpro :)

Comment: I think this is wrong. Try 33 (base 4), which equals 15 (base 10). 5 > 3.

Comment: @luserdroog `check(33, 5)` returns 1, which is correct. Why are you converting to base 10?

Comment: With respect, it is *you* who are converting to base 10 by using `%10` and `/= 10`. And are you running the `33` through a base-4 input routine? Or is that a base-10 (regular Decimal number) as well?

Comment: @luserdroog The `33` is input by the user in base 10 (that's just how the OP reads the input from stdin using `%d`). Then he wants to verify if the digits of `33` are also valid digits for a base `5` number.

Comment: One was me. After I got 3 and no explanation. I don't think I've said anything *incorrect*, but with OP's peculiar processing method, perhaps it is indeed *not useful.* I will remove my downvote if you make an edit because I cannot remove my downvote unless you make an edit.

Comment: Well at least I'll get a badge for deleting. :)